# Express routing - calling routes inside routes

Tags: express, routes

I have a get route for rendering register.pug with data (title and contries).

```
// GET /register.pug
router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('register', {
    title: 'Register', 
    countries: [] //countries
  });
});
```

I also have a route that retrieves contries from my database, can I use that to get the 'countries'-data for my rendering above?

```
// GET /contries
router.get("/", function(req, res){

    //Result from Sequelize query
    var contries = [{
        name: Denmark,
        ISO: DK
    }, {
        name: Sweden,
        ISO: SE
    }];

    res.status(200).send(contries);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't directly use those values as it is inside another function.

You could create a middleware function which gets the countries from the database and uses the next function to call your routings afterwards with the countries object:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // how I imagine the sequelize call
    Country.findAll().then(function(countries) {
        next(countries);
    });
});

app.get('/register', function(countries, req, res, next) {
    res.render('register', {
        title: 'Register', 
        countries: countries
    };
});

app.get('/', function(countries, req, res, next) {
    res.status(200).send(contries);
});
```

Also if you are trying to send countries as json, in the '/' routing, you might want to use the `json` function instead of `send`. http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json

Comment: Thanks ikkuh :) Is this the way you would do it, or would you drop the middleware function and just have the sequelize statement inside both routes?

Comment: I would duplicate the sequelize statement in both routes my find calls are currently all single sequelize calls.

Comment: This is also because I don't know how to easily setup middleware functions before specific routes and not all routes as in my example. I'm still learning express.

Comment: I think that might be the best as well. Thank you for your response :)